# How to get the default asp.net membership provider name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

How can I get the default asp.net membership provider name from code (C#)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Membership.Provider.Name` this will return the name used in `web.config` file

EDIT: Works only in case I've set a `defaultProvider` in the `membership` section

Comment: Works only in case I've set a `defaultProvider` in the `membership` section

Answer (score 1):

You can always access to web.config file using 
`WebConfigurationManager.GetSection`